# Microsoft Graph API Returning "Access Token Validation Error"

Tags: azure, angular, oauth, jwt, azure-ad-graph-api

I've registered an Angular2 app with Microsoft that's completely client-side to access the Graph API. I've enabled Implicit Grant Flow and I'm able to obtain a JWT successfully after login and first-time authorization.

The URL fragment even says that it's a bearer token, like so:

`http://localhost:4200/loginRedirect#access_token={JWT_TOKEN_HERE}&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&session_state={state_guid}`

My redirect to authenticate, for reference, looks like this:

`window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=" + encodeURIComponent('https://graph.windows.net') + "&response_type=token&client_id=" + this._config.clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(this._config.redirectUri);`

Despite including the acquired JWT in my the header of my Graph API request:

`Authorization: Bearer {JWT_TOKEN_HERE}`

I get a 401: `Access Token Validation Error`

I assumed that since I successfully retrieved that token it told me was a `Bearer`, it would've worked, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong resource URI. Azure AD Graph API is `https://graph.windows.net`.

Microsoft Graph API resource URI is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`, try it.

Azure AD Graph API is AAD's API, whereas Microsoft Graph API covers also Office 365 services. Confusing naming though.

Comment: I would've spent hours looking at other parts of my code had you not pointed that out; thank you!